# BitLocker demands the keys on each system restart

Tags: bitlocker

I use my external SSD to boot Windows via a USB-C port. However, I have to enter the BitLocker key each time I restart my machine even without unplugging the USB port. How to fix this?

Comment: What protectors are enabled for the disk in `manage-bde -protectors -get C:`?

Comment: @user1686 numerical password and TPM.

Comment: @user1686 also trying `manage-bde -autounlock -enable c:`  I got `ERROR: Automatic unlocking cannot be used on the OS volume.` message.

Comment: “How to fix this?” - You can’t because you’re running up against a security feature of BitLocker.

Comment: @Ramhound the same drive works without BitLocker prompt when is connected to another Laptop

Comment: When you use the TPM protector, you bind it to the TPM chip of a certain laptop. On that laptop, it will boot, on others, it will need the recovery key. That's expected behavior. You would need to use a password protector instead of the TPM protector if you want portability and comfort.

Comment: You can’t store the same key to BitLocker on two TPMs. Every time BitLocker detects a system configuration change it will prompt you for the Recovery key. There is a reason Microsoft discontinued support for Windows2Go which unlikely every supported BitLocker.

Comment: @BerndSchwanenmeister how can i make the new laptop the primary one, I don't use the old one much.

Comment: As said: use a password protector instead of the tpm protector. There's no primary/secondary setting needed. On an elevated command line: manage-bde -protectors  c: -delete -type tpm, then next line: manage-bde -protectors -add c: -pw